# Exporting 2 files to Excel from Access with VBA results in a Read-Only file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm currently running some macros in Access 2016 that exports 2 different files to Excel.  The 2nd file is Ready-Only.  Is there any way to prevent this?  Here is the code I'm using:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "File1", "R:\File1.xlsx", True
```

'   do some stuff to File 1

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "File2", "R:\File2.xlsx", True
```

'   do some stuff to File 2

The goal is to have both File 1 and File 2 as NOT Read-Only.

Thanks for the help and suggestions......

Comment: What is the "some stuff"? Exporting multiple files won't cause them to be read-only.

Comment: @Warcupine..........."some stuff" is mainly formatting so it is more user friendly

Comment: Well its probably that that is causing the read-only. The code in your question will not cause that on its own.

Comment: @Warcupine....user error...............I had xlapp.visible = false.....so a previous version of the file existed.  I ran a couple of lines to change xlapp.visible = true....The existing file was displayed.  I closed that file and then re-ran my macro......no more read only....Thanks for the help